# OpenOrd layout for gephi 0.9.1

Tags: java, gephi

I am trying to install the OpenOrd layout with gephi version 0.9.1. From the plugin site I find the latest to be suitable for version 0.8.2. When I try to install it manually I get

> Some plugins require plugin org.gephi.utils.collection to be installed.
>   The plugin org.gephi.utils.collection is requested in version 0.7.1. 
>   The following plugin is affected:       OpenOrdLayout

I also downloaded and manually placed org.gephi.utils.collection.jar in gephi/modules dir but nothing changed.

Some help?

Comment: The change to Gephi 0.9 made all plugins from previous versions unusable so this will not work until someone migrates the plugin to Gephi 0.9

Comment: I managed to install the `org.gephi.utils.collection` using the manual plugin installer and then it installed correctly.

Comment: Good to know. I didn't know it is possible because the olugin architecture has changed so my answer was generic. I also thought they had created the OpenOrd already. Could you post your comment as answer in case someone finds it useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

I managed to install the `org.gephi.utils.collection` using the manual plugin installer and then the layout installed correctly.

Comment: From which site did you downloaded the org.gephi.utils.collection? I downloaded a zip file (containing a Jar), but I don't know how to install it

Comment: OK done. For the record the org-gephi-utils-collection.nbm can be downloaded fron here: https://github.com/mbastian/nbms-repository/blob/master/master/org-gephi-utils-collection.nbm